# Polymer : My core-list is no rendered when is in core-animated-pages element

Tags: css, polymer, web-component, core-elements

I have a render problem(no render) of a core-list element when my custom element is in core-animated-pages

here is a jsfiddle  when it works( grey list)  ==> album-grid  outside core-animated-pages
http://jsfiddle.net/flagadajones/yq30u78d/

here is a jsfiddle when id doesn't works( no grey list)  ==> album-grid  inside core-animated-pages
[http://jsfiddle.net/flagadajones/m87sd0x3/2//](http://jsfiddle.net/flagadajones/m87sd0x3/2/)

could you help me thanks

Here is my code:

```
 <script src="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js">
  </script>

  <link href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-drawer-panel/core-drawer-panel.html" rel="import">
  <link href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-icons/core-icons.html" rel="import">
  <link href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-icon-button/core-icon-button.html" rel="import">
  <link href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-animated-pages/core-animated-pages.html" rel="import">
  <link href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html" rel="import">
  <link href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-list/core-list.html" rel="import" >

  <style>
   html, body {
      margin: 0;
      -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
      remote-app{ 
      display: block;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

  </style>
  </head>
  <body fit>
    <remote-app ></remote-app>


<polymer-element name="album-detail" attributes="album" layout vertical>
  <template>
    <style>
      #details {
        width: 740px;
        margin: auto;
        height: 100%;
        box-shadow: 0 27px 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        poosition:relative;
      }
      .mycard {
        height: 540px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        text-align: start;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
      }
      .card-left {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color:blue;
      }

      .btn{
        background-color:red;
        height:63px;
      }
      .title{
        background-color:yellow;
        color:black;
      }
      .info{
        height:200px
      }
      .item{
        height:48px;
        color:black;
        background-color:grey;
      }
    </style>
    <section id="details" class="details" >

      <div class="mycard " layout vertical>
        <div layout horizontal>
          <div class="card-left" ></div>
          <div  flex auto-horizontal layout vertical class="info">
            <div layout vertical flex class="title">
              <div flex auto>title</div>
              <div flex  auto>title2</div>
            </div>
            <div layout horizontal >
              <a  flex class="btn">aaa</a>
              <a flex  class="btn">bbb</a>
              <a flex class="btn">ccc</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <core-list id="list3" data="{{album.pistes}}" height="48" flex>
          <template>
            <div layout horizontal  class="item" center>
              <div>{{index}} toto {{model.name}}</div>
            </div>
          </template>
        </core-list>
      </div>
    </section>

  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({

    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>


<polymer-element name="remote-app" layout vertical>

  <template>
    <style>

      [drawer] {
        background-color: #B99588;
        border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
      }
      [main] {
        background-color: #4F7DC9;
        height:100%;
      }
      :host {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .album-grid {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      #pages {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
       .item{
        height:48px;
        color:black;
        background-color:grey;
      }
    </style>
    <core-drawer-panel>
      <div drawer>
      </div>
      <div main>
        <album-detail album="{{ele}}" flex/>
        <!--core-animated-pages id="pages" selected="0" >
            <album-detail  album="{{ele}}" />
        </core-animated-pages-->
      </div>
    </core-drawer-panel>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
    ele:{pistes:[{name:"1"},{name:"2"},{name:"3"},{name:"4"}]}
    }
           );
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 2):

Kevin Schaaf has helped me fix this issue. Please see this [thread](https://github.com/Polymer/core-list/issues/47#issuecomment-68797508).

Note that you will first need to get the latest version of Polymer (currently **5.2**) from bower. Then go to `core-animated-pages.html` and find this piece of code -

```
if (!oldItem) {
    this.applySelection(this.selectedItem, true);
    return;
}
```

Now add `this.async(this.notifyResize);` after `applySelection` -

```
if (!oldItem) {
    this.applySelection(this.selectedItem, true);
    this.async(this.notifyResize);
    return;
}
```

That's it! Your code should be working without calling `updateSize` or any other tricks.

I think after **5.2** this fix will be included into package so you don't need to do this. But for now it's just simple change that you need to make.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue with `Polymer 0.5.1`.

For now I switched `core-animated-pages` back to `core-pages` and it renders properly.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a 'fix' but a work around.  I found that putting any text or even a  <br/> tag between the core-list element and its template element, causes it to render in core-animated-pages.

Maybe that will help someone troubleshooting the problem as well.